# Problem with pinging in STM32F767 + FreeRTOS + LWIP

Tags: freertos, lwip

I have an application with freertos on stm32f767. There was no problem with tcp/ip running on my application with lwip middleware. But now adding some new code somewhere in other threads that is not relevant to lwip causes some problems in pinging. When I ping my  board (after adding new code), the mcu does not respond completely. Some ping response packets receives too late and time-out occurred.  This packet loss is occurred randomly and when I comment the added code everything is ok and ping response packet receives completely without any problem.

The problem is that there is no relation between the added code and lwip thread. In other words,  adding code in some part of code (independent of what code is doing as I tested) makes this problem.

I guessed that  there is a problem with stack or heap memory overflow but when I increase freertos stack or global stack the problem is not solved.

I think this a bug in lwip implementation but I don't know how can I solve?

Please help me.